# Difficulties in understanding ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

I have problems understanding on why *ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver* throws an Exception.
I have written a custom *@RestControllerAdvice* ExceptionHandler to catch Exceptions thrown by my Spring Boot application. After the catch my ExceptionHandler returns as a response the message from the thrown exception. But I still get a log message from *ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver* and I can't figure out why.

Here the Log message:

```
2022-05-04 10:08:53.043  INFO 17600 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] at.sds.wm.common.CommonExceptionHandler  : Equipment Barbell 660Kg exists already. Either id already taken or name combined with same equipment already saved
2022-05-04 10:08:53.049  WARN 17600 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [at.sds.wm.equipment.exceptions.EquipmentExistsAlreadyException: Equipment Barbell 660Kg exists already. Either id already taken or name combined with same equipment already saved]
```

I first thought, that the *ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver* gets called because my *ExceptionHandler* throws an Exception but that isn't the case.

Any tips and tricks on how to surpress the second Log, or could someone explain me why the *ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver* gets called?

Below my code snippet for the ExceptionHandler part that gets called:

```
    @ExceptionHandler(value = {WorkoutExistsAlreadyException.class, EquipmentExistsAlreadyException.class, ExerciseExistsAlreadyException.class})
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
    public String handleExistsAlreadyException(RuntimeException ex) {
        log.info(ex.getMessage());
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related with the application property `spring.mvc.log-resolved-exception`. This is by default set to false in `spring-boot` but if you use `spring-boot-devtools` then it is switched to true.

So in that case you have to declare `spring.mvc.log-resolved-exception = false` for exception handler resolver to stop writting warns about exceptions.

[Referenced Spring boot doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.web.spring.mvc.log-resolved-exception)